# Varchar issue on Mysql 2147483647

Tags: mysql, varchar

Having the `2147483647` MYSQL issue.

When inserting an 11 digit number in the telephone field i am getting this number in return saved in the `DB: 2147483647`

TEL is set as `VARCHAR` not `INT` tough.

Also, on a database hosted on `SERVER` 1 i have the same exact database table and not having the same issue tough?! what might be?

This is the SQL and PHP

```
tel_no  varchar(20) utf8_general_ci  Yes    NULL
mob_no  varchar(20) utf8_general_ci  Yes    NULL
```

That's the MYSQL. Yes i am inserting an 11 digit number as string in the DB

```
$telno = GetValue($post['tel_no']);
$mobno = GetValue($post['mob_no']); 

$sql = "UPDATE ".$this->dbpre."bookings SET tel_no='$telno', mob_no='$mobno'...
```

Can you please help? I am getting crazy!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255724/incorrect-integer-2147483647-is-inserted-into-mysql

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Are you using the same front-end to accept the phone number to test both platforms? Always good to show your SQL as well.

Comment: Somewhere you have some non-SQL code that pulls out the varchar column and starts treating it as an integer.

Comment: Are you saying you have a VARCHAR(11) and you're putting an 11 digit number into it and getting back something else? Maybe it's not MySQL, but your programming language that is not able to handle 64 bit numbers...?

Comment: I am not having the same issue on a different database hosted on another server .. that's very strange. Can it be a server setting of some sort?

Comment: Have you printed the SQL (`$sql`) so you can see whether the trouble is in the PHP or in MySQL itself?  If the problem is actually in the PHP, can you force `$telno` to be a string by concatenating an empty string with the value from `GetValue()`?  Does `GetValue()` force the numeric conversion?

Answer (score 5):

2147483647 is the largest int value for mysql. Just change the type from int to bigint.

Comment: While you are right that the number is largest (signed) int value, the answer isn't in changing to bigint, answer is changing from int to varchar since telephone numbers can't be saved as integers correctly (due to unknown lengths, prefixes if applicable, space characters for formatting etc).

Comment: thanks @N.B. 
I guess you are right for international numbers, especially when [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Integer Types (Exact Value) - INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255724/incorrect-integer-2147483647-is-inserted-into-mysql#answer-17783287)

Answer (score -1):

solution : just change the type from int to **bigint** or varchar to **bigint**.