# MySqli error using time() in query to update a table

Tags: php, database, mysqli

MySqli problem:
i used this query to update a field in table.

```
mysqli_query($con, " UPDATE users SET profile_pic = '$img_name' WHERE id = '$id' ");
```

where

```
$img_name = time().$id;
```

and

```
$id = 3;
```

when I `echo $img_name`, it give correct result.
but value stored in database it gives 2147483647 ie maximum integer value for my 32bit computer.

Comment: Which type are `profile_pic` and `id` in your database?

Comment: either change your `profile_pic` to `bigint` or a `varchar` - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10255765/689579 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/17783238/689579

Comment: `2147483647` it's the max int allowed in mysql, for example time() output this number `1381254130`, then when you add the id the result number is greater than the allowed for int in mysql, try with bigint instead int on mysql. remember store the file name without extension or change to vaarchar

Answer (score 2):

1. get rid of `profile_pic` field in the table
2. when uploading image, rename it to `'profile'.$id.'.jpg'`