# Saving PHP variable to MySQL INT is always 0

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having a problem passing a variable to be saved as INT in MySQL.  The closest thing I could find to my issue is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255724/incorrect-integer-2147483647-is-inserted-into-mysql) but I have already verified that I am not using single and double quotes.  When I `print_r($this->session->userdata('subdomain'))` I see the correct subdomain id on my screen (in this case 10), but when I try passing this using $params it always save subdomain_id as 0 and I can not figure out why.

Here is Project_assignees_model:

```
function add_prefix_project_assignees($params)
{
    $this->db->insert('prefix_project_assignees',$params);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Here is my Project controller (Specifically it is the `$assignees` array):

```
function edit($entry_id)
    {   
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('client_id','Client Id','required|integer');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title','Project Title','required|max_length[255]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('project_status','Project Status','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('project_details','Project Details','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('project_estimated_hours','Project Estimated Hours','required|max_length[255]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('end','Project Deadline','required');

        if($this->form_validation->run())     
        {   
            date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
            $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");

            $params = array(
                'subdomain_id' => $this->session->userdata('subdomain'),
                'client_id' => $this->input->post('client_id'),
                'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                'project_status' => $this->input->post('project_status'),
                'project_details' => $this->input->post('project_details'),
                'project_last_updated' => $date,
                'project_estimated_hours' => $this->input->post('project_estimated_hours'),
                'start' => $this->input->post('start'),
                'end' => $this->input->post('end'),
                'owner_id' => get_current_user_id(),
            );

            $prefix_projects_id = $this->Project_model->update_prefix_projects($entry_id,$params);

            $assignees = array(
                'subdomain_id' => $this->session->userdata('subdomain'),
                'project_id' => $entry_id,
                'user_id' => $this->input->post('assignee'),
            );

            $this->load->model('Project_assignee_model');

            $insertAssignees = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($assignees['user_id']); $i++)
            {
                //Get user_id from ID
                $userID = $assignees['user_id'][$i];

                $insertAssignees[$i] = array('project_id' => $entry_id, 'user_id' => $assignees['user_id'][$i]); // $insert is ready for insert_batch

                $prefix_assignees = $this->Project_assignee_model->add_prefix_project_assignees($insertAssignees[$i]);
            }

            //redirect('project/index');
        }
        else
        {   
            $this->load->model('Client_model');
            $data['prefix_clients'] = $this->Client_model->get_all_prefix_clients();
            $data['prefix_projects'] = $this->Project_model->get_prefix_projects($entry_id);
            $data['prefix_users'] = $this->aauth->list_users();
            $this->load->model('Project_assignee_model');
            $data['prefix_assignees'] = $this->Project_assignee_model->get_prefix_project_assignees($entry_id);
            $this->load->view('project/edit',$data);
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

**Why does `print_r` show the correct subdomain_id but when it is saved to database it saves as 0?**

*******UPDATE*******

Just for reference, this works:

```
$assignees = array(
       'subdomain_id' => 10,
       'project_id' => $entry_id,
       'user_id' => $this->input->post('assignee'),
);
```

But this does not (Even though printing the userdata for subdomain gives me 10):

```
$assignees = array(
       'subdomain_id' => $this->session->userdata('subdomain'),
       'project_id' => $entry_id,
       'user_id' => $this->input->post('assignee'),
);
```

Comment: Function is `update_prefix_project_assignees`, and you are executing `$prefix_projects_id = $this->Project_model->update_prefix_projects($entry_id,$params);`, what does `update_prefix_projects`?

Comment: Immediately after that I sort through the multi-select values for `$assignees`, then I loop through each assignee and add it to the db using `$prefix_assignees = $this->Project_assignee_model->add_prefix_project_assignees($insertAssignees[$i]);` which works fine if I replace `$this->session->userdata('subdomain')` with `10` for example in the `$assignees` array

Comment: and on insert you leave out `subdomain_id` at all on purpose?

Comment: Maybe a little more clarification is due, I have a projects table which saves the project id, title, description, etc.  Then I have a separate table for assigning users to projects.  My controller above takes a forms input and saves it to the project table and then sorts through all of the assignees and inserts them into the project_assignee table

Comment: yes, and in the line `$insertAssignees[$i] = array('project_id' => $entry_id, 'user_id' => $assignees['user_id'][$i]);` you don't add the 'subdomain_id'

Comment: Do you have `$this->load->library('session');`? You need that to use `$this->session`

Comment: Yes, if I do `print_r($this->session->userdata('subdomain'));` It shows me 10, but when I use it in my controller as the `$assignees` params it saves to the column as 0.

Comment: I'm kinda confused, if your print `$this->session->userdata('subdomain')` in controller it prints 10, but saves 0, if you change manually to 10 then it saves the right value?

Comment: @cpatricio yes, exactly, what would cause that?

Comment: Maybe due to wrong type, from session is string, so `intval($this->session->userdata('subdomain'))` should work.

Comment: embarrassingly enough, I just realized my problem and it was completely obvious after hours of trying to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I guess it just takes writing it out for others before I realize my problem.  When I loop through each assignee to add them to the table I realized I was not passing the subdomain_id with it.

I had this:

```
$insertAssignees[$i] = array('project_id' => $entry_id, 'user_id' => $assignees['user_id'][$i]); // $insert is ready for insert_batch
```

Needed to be changed to have subdomain_id included

```
$insertAssignees[$i] = array('subdomain_id' => $this->session->userdata('subdomain'), 'project_id' => $entry_id, 'user_id' => $assignees['user_id'][$i]); // $insert is ready for insert_batch
```

Comment: Another testament to [rubber duck debugging](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).