# MySQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP does not returns current timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have inserted timestamp in my table using two methods:
1 - `time()` php code
2 - `insert into mytable (...,....,time) values(...,...,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())`.
Inserted values are: 1) 1495353761 
and 2)2147483647. The type of `time` in DB is `INT(11)`. My Question is why this is happening and what should I do?
(host: localhost)

Comment: Can u post the format of the php timestamp...??

Comment: it is a number. int(11)

Comment: Sometimes it varies with the geographic location. Set the date_default_timezone_set() in ur PHP to get the timestamp of ur location. 
OR 
`If u think timestamp should be same, they'll be never same, timestamp changes every milli second`

Comment: I know about changes in time-stamp. time zone differs 24 hours in maximum. Difference is about 15 years in my case

Comment: [Your answer is here...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17783287/1415724) and I quote that answer: *"2147483647 is the largest int value for mysql. Just change the type from int to bigint."* - @ManManam Let me know if you want me to post my comment as an answer.

Comment: @ManManam you're not responding to ^ - you will need to ping me back, I won't look at this thread all day waiting for a response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect Integer (2147483647) is inserted into MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255724/incorrect-integer-2147483647-is-inserted-into-mysql)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank You For Your Answer. You are right. I have changed the type to BIGINT(20). It returned 20170523021022. If you look at the number it is the concat of date and time. So I user UNIX_TIMESTAMP(). It resolved my problem.

Comment: @ManManam welcome; I posted my answer below that can be marked as solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect Integer (2147483647) is inserted into MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255724/incorrect-integer-2147483647-is-inserted-into-mysql)

Comment: @Fred-ii- The problem was using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for a column of type `INT(11)` . We should use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`. If we use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, it works even for `INT(11)` type.

Comment: @ManManam it's usually best to use mysql's datetime types rather than int's and you stand at being faced with the UNIX 2038 bug later on. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of time is int(11) in my table. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` works for `DATETIME` type. If you want an Integer as timestamp, you should use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

Answer (score 0):

2147483647 one is wrong. It's equivalent to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT

Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647

You send something wrong. Double check your type of time field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you see there is no parameter. I jast have inserted a row in a query using phpmyadmin. method is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` which returns current timestamp

Comment: What is type of your time field? e.g: It works with DATETIME.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I changed my answer to a community wiki.

---

2147483647 is the largest int value for mysql. Just change the type from int to bigint.

Pulled/quoted from this answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17783287/1415724

---

From comments:

> *"@Fred-ii- Thank You For Your Answer. You are right. I have changed the type to BIGINT(20). It returned 20170523021022. If you look at the number it is the concat of date and time. So I user UNIX_TIMESTAMP(). It resolved my problem. – Man Manam"*

Comment: Note: I couldn't close the question since I had already voted as unclear.