# Incorrect integer being returned by mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Before marking the answer as a duplicate, I would like to say that I have been to this Q&A: [Incorrect Integer (2147483647) is inserted into MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255724/incorrect-integer-2147483647-is-inserted-into-mysql) and my problems is the other way around. An integer is being returned wrongly by MySQL. As the question before, I'm working with `Steam API` and they happen to have really long `IDs`.

Here are the following steps that I followed:

1. Get the id of  `Dota2_items` group (`103582791433341052`) and insert into the `DB`.
2. The id from the group is stored correctly into the database
3. Get the same number from the database which now returns `103582791433341060`

`GiveawayTasks::where('id', 1)->first()` which translating from Laravel `"select * from giveaway_task where id = 1"`

Notice the 8 values of difference between the two IDs. It looks like that the database has added 8 values to the initial ID.

To tackle the problem, I did `PHP_MAX_INT` which returns `9223372036854776000`. Exactly what I was expecting coming from a `64 bit machine`. Now I tried to subtract the `PHP_MAX_INT` and the number from the database to see if the int is bigger than the `PHP_MAX_INT` can handle:

`PHP_MAX_INT - <Number from the database>` -> `9223372036854776000 - 103582791433341052 = 9119789245421434948` which leads me to the conclusion that I'm not trying to store more in one variable than what `PHP_MAX_INT` can handle.

I'm not sure what is going on here since this is beyond my expertise. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using the Laravel framework, but I don't think that is relevant to the case.

Comment: Sounds a lot like an implicit conversion to `double` which cannot store the last digit(s) of your large value and rounds up. See e.g.  [MySQL Refman 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html), which has a similar example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Integers` use `String` instead for your `ids`. You're getting that error because `mysql` has a max integer value of `2147483647 for 32-bit` compared to your input `103582791433341052`. It might solve the problem if you treat that `integers` as a `String`.

Comment: How can I store the correct value into the database but not get the value that is correctly stored?

Comment: MySQL or something in-beween might convert your big number into a 64-bit `double` value.

Comment: It will retain the same value but you can't perform mathematical expressions there for it's already a string. You might want to adjust your schema by chaging `Int` -> `varchar`

Comment: @Thedude You may also want to look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use BigInt as opposed to Int for the 'id' column type. See [this table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html) for details.

Edit: Strings might be a better alternative as suggested in the comments below.

Comment: please provide an example on how he would do so.

Comment: Nope. He is storing "Steam IDs" which should be treated as strings.

Comment: @TurboJ I already did the conversion from bigInteger (unsigned) to strings. It is returning the correct value now but it would be nice to know why this is happening

Comment: Strings can be an alternative, but why use them over BigInts?

Comment: Steam might just change their ID scheme tomorrow if they feel their IDs are a bit too long... Also, you don't need to use math expressions on an ID field.

Comment: @Thedude my only guess is that somewhere along the line, the max int supported is less than your value.